# Распознавание двух объектов на изображении при помощи python

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Есть подробные туториалы по тренировке нейронной сети для поиска двух объектов на картинке? Книги читал и в интернете подобные инструкции находил, но подробных, которые подойдут для новичка, не находил.

Comment: https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю... Но думал, что есть более подробные...